# is it possible to record the nodejs function call stack time

Tags: node.js, performance

I have a nodejs v16.20.2 server using the express `"express": "^4.18.2"` framework. Now I am facing a issue that one of the api was very slow. This api was a little complex and call many function, I was wonder is it possible to trace the server side function call stack and print the time of every call stack layer? so that I could tracing which function takes the most of the response time.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking at entirely sync flows, you can use the [profiler](https://nodejs.org/api/inspector.html#cpu-profiler) directly:

```js
import { Session } from 'node:inspector/promises';
import fs from 'node:fs';
const session = new Session();
session.connect();

await session.post('Profiler.enable');
await session.post('Profiler.start');
// Invoke business logic under measurement here, in your case the express handler

// some time later...
const { profile } = await session.post('Profiler.stop');

// Write profile to disk, upload, etc.
fs.writeFileSync('./profile.cpuprofile', JSON.stringify(profile));
```

However in most cases that's not what people are looking for since they want to measure asynchronous flows and not sync ones.

The product you're looking for is called an APM, we supply hooks for APMs through [`async_hooks`](https://nodejs.org/api/async_hooks.html) that lets you time things across async call stacks and promises.

APMs use the fact you can run code in context and track causality and additionally wrap common libraries like express, databases and other libraries to time specific parts of the callstack.

For example [elastic APM](https://github.com/elastic/apm-agent-nodejs) is a free and open source option you can use. There is also [application insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/nodejs) from my employer which isn't free. Other options include New Relic and DataDog but StackOverflow isn't for library recommendations.

Note: please upgrade Node.js we don't support end of life versions of Node.js